# Phonegap play sound onload

Tags: javascript, android, audio, cordova

Hey guys I have been trying to solve this problem for a few weeks but no such luck. I have read a number of posts on the subject but nothing seems to work.
All I want to do is play a sound file when the app loads... 
Somebody please help me =( The is for android version 14.

CODE

```
newsrc  = "soundOff.png";

var sound = new Audio('sound/soundtrack.mp3');
sound.play();


$(".sound").bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( newsrc == "soundOff.png" ) {
        document.getElementById("sound").src = "img/soundOff.png";
        document.getElementById("sound").alt = "Sound Off";
        newsrc  = "soundOn.png";
        sound.pause();
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("sound").src = "img/soundOn.png";
        document.getElementById("sound").alt = "Sound On";
        newsrc  = "soundOff.png";
        sound.play();
    }


} );

</script>
```

Comment: What is your error? Logcat or unexpected results? Hard to debug without knowing what is happening

Comment: Sorry but, how do I check errors when its running on a phone/table? Everything works great in the browser but doesnt work on a device. Do i use the emulator?

Comment: Do you use eclipse or Android studio? if so, just open your Logcat and use that to debug.